# Merge / flatten sub aggs into main agg

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there away in elasticsearch to get the results back in a sort of flattend form (multiple child/sub aggs?

For instance currently i am trying to get back all product types and their status (online / offline).

This is what i end up with:
aggs

```
[
{ key: SuperProduct, doc_count:3, subagg:[
                                         {status:online, doc_count:1},
                                         {status:offline, doc_count:2}
                                         ]
},
{ key: SuperProduct2, doc_count:10, subagg:[
                                         {status:online, doc_count:7},
                                         {status:offline, doc_count:3}
                                         ]
```

Charting libraries tend to like it flattened so i was wondering if elasticsearch could probide it in this sort of manner:

```
[
  { products_key: 'SuperProduct', status_key:'online', doc_count:1},
  { products_key: 'SuperProduct', status_key:'offline', doc_count:2},
  { products_key: 'SuperProduct2', status_key:'online', doc_count:7},
  { products_key: 'SuperProduct2', status_key:'offline', doc_count:3}
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) which you can use to link two terms aggregations:

```json
// POST /i/_search

{
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations": {
        "distribution": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {"product": {"terms": {"field": "product.keyword"}}},
                    {"status": {"terms": {"field": "status.keyword"}}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in following structure:

```json
{
    "aggregations": {
        "distribution": {
            "after_key": {
                "product": "B",
                "status": "online"
            },
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": {
                        "product": "A",
                        "status": "offline"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 3
                },
                {
                    "key": {
                        "product": "A",
                        "status": "online"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": {
                        "product": "B",
                        "status": "offline"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": {
                        "product": "B",
                        "status": "online"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If for any reason composite aggregation doesn't fulfill your needs, y[ou can create (via copy_to or by concatenation) or simulate (via scripted fields) field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation) that would uniquely identify bucket. In our project we went with concatenation (partially for the necessity to collapse on this field), e.g. `{"bucket": "SuperProductA:online"}`, which results in dirtier output (you'll have to decode that field back or use top hits to get original values) but still does the job.

Comment: thanks for the information, that seems to work great - i just need to figure out if the charting library allows me to pass in things like key.product and key.status (i hope they do). Thanks again